# How to detect group SMS conversation

Tags: android, sms

i build small SMS app and i have a question. Stock SMS app and for example GO SMS gives me option to send one message to more than one person and after that both applications show me that in conversations list.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18780140/group_sms.jpeg

But how can i detect that in my own app?
I tried to use: content://mms-sms/conversations but it shows me only one conversation with one address and there isn't any special sign look:
(I sent "Hyg" message to numbers: 1003 and 0001 (different message than this on screenshot))

```
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): body Hyg                                                        
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): person null                                                     
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): sub null                                                        
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): subject null                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): retr_st null                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): type 5                                                          
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): date 1330538860294                                              
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): ct_cls null                                                     
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): sub_cs null                                                     
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): _id 510                                                         
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): read 1                                                          
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): ct_l null                                                       
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): tr_id null                                                      
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): st null                                                         
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): msg_box null                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): thread_id 86                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): reply_path_present null                                         
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): m_cls null                                                      
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): read_status null                                                
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): ct_t null                                                       
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): status -1                                                       
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): retr_txt_cs null                                                
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): d_rpt null                                                      
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): error_code 0                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): m_id null                                                       
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): m_type null                                                     
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): v null                                                          
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): exp null                                                        
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): pri null                                                        
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): service_center null                                             
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): address 1003                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): rr null                                                         
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): rpt_a null                                                      
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): resp_txt null                                                   
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): locked 0                                                        
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): resp_st null                                                    
D/ConversationAdapter(13012): m_size null
```

also content://sms/conversations dosen't give me anything

```
D/ContactAIOApp(  387): thread_id 89
D/ContactAIOApp(  387): msg_count 2
D/ContactAIOApp(  387): snippet Test
```

Of course i could "enter" to the every conversation and check every message looking for different numbers, but it will be very slow

Comment: @user1189159..Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sorry but no. What i did is iterate over all messages in inbox and chceck if more than 1 number is included in one conversation. It is slow, but couldn't find better solution

Comment: Do you able to send sms to more than one person at a time??..i meann send sms to x creates a threadid and y creates a another threadid and if i send sms to both x and y then new threadid..Did you done that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but here is how you can do it.

If you use "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true" Uri, then there is a column with name "recipient_ids" which will have an array of ids of the group message. 
From the id, you can find out the address of the recipients.